# Testcafe, test is not running?

Tags: ubuntu, automated-tests, chromium, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to get started with Testcafe.

I have installed it globally with npm and I'm following the official example from https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/getting-started/

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test('My first test', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('#developer-name', 'John Smith')
        .click('#submit-button');

    const articleHeader = await Selector('.result-content').find('h1');

    // Obtain the text of the article header
    let headerText = await articleHeader.innerText;
});
```

I'm on an old Ubuntu (12.04 I think) using chromium.

I launch the test and can see the browser load the page and the message "Getting started" shows on the console.

However nothing happens after that.
I dont see the name of the test, results or anything.
Nothing happens on the browser either (no text being typed).

It is probably something silly, but I cant really seem to find what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Would you please let me know your chromium version?

Comment: it was installed with apt-get, so I suppose it should be this one: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/chromium-browser

Comment: I cannot verify it because I'm convinced it must be a problem with using old nodejs/npm, so I'm in the process of updating to Ubuntu 16.04 to get the newest packages

Comment: Please let me know whether or not the issue is resolved after the update.

Comment: Yeps, now running Ubuntu 16.04, with nodejs 8 and newest chromium and it works. So either the nodejs or chromium version was the issue.

Comment: As a side note Firefox wasnt working either, would never get past a loading icon.

Comment: Would you please send me a link to your web page with a test (2-3 steps) so that I can check the issue locally? In addition, let me know your FF version.

Comment: Now after the update to 16.04 all runs fine, tested with Firefox, Chrome and Chromium

Comment: I have added the example to the question

Comment: And I don't know what the FF version was, I suppose it was firefox 52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, according to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/firefox

Comment: Thank you for informing me that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

As the question's author found, either the nodejs or chromium version was the issue.

Upgrading to the latest versions resolved the issue.